# Python: vending machine

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

The program offers items, has the user pay for items, gives the items, and updates the stock of each item. It seems to work more or less. I have 2 questions:

1. I don't know how to exit the vending machine program after the user answers "n" to "buy something else? (y/n): ".
2. Is there a way to make the code simpler/better?

```py
def vend():

    a = {'item': 'choc', 'price': 1.5, 'stock': 2}
    b = {'item': 'pop', 'price': 1.75, 'stock': 1}
    c = {'item': 'chips', 'price': 2.0, 'stock': 3}
    d = {'item': 'gum', 'price': 0.50, 'stock': 1}
    e = {'item': 'mints', 'price': 0.75, 'stock': 3}
    items = [a, b, c, d, e]
    cim = 0 # cash in machine

    print('welcome to vending machine! \n***************')

    # show items, prices
    def show(items):
        print('\nitems available \n***************')
    
        for item in items:      
            if item.get('stock') == 0:
                items.remove(item)
        for item in items:
            print(item.get('item'), item.get('price'))
        
        print('***************\n')
    
    # have user choose item
    while True:
        show(items)
        selected = input('select item: ')
        for item in items:
            if selected == item.get('item'):
                selected = item               
                price = selected.get('price')
                while cim < price:
                    cim = float(input('insert ' + str(price - cim) + ': '))   
                else:
                    print('you got ' + selected.get('item'))
                    selected['stock'] -= 1
                    cim -= price
                    print('cash remaining: ' + str(cim))
                    a = input('buy something else? (y/n): ')
                    if a == 'n':
                        if cim != 0:
                            print(str(cim) + ' refunded')
                            cim = 0
                            print('thank you, have a nice day!\n')
                            break                        
                        else:
                            print('thank you, have a nice day!\n')
                            break                        
                    else:
                        continue
                        
                    
   
vend()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) I don't know how to exit the the vending machine program after the
>   user answers 'n' to 'buy something else? (y/n): '.

The **break** statement in Python breaks out of the first **for** or **while** loop which encloses it.  You are only exiting the **for** loop that you show.  The **while True** condition keeps you looping forever.

However, you did something smart, you enclosed all the vending machine functionality in your **vend** function.  If you use a **return** statement in place of **break**, you will not only exit your **vend** function, you will reach the end of your whole program and quit as you want.

The **return** statement is also used to return values from function calls, but you don't need to do that in your case.

Also, you don't need, and shouldn't have, two separate exits from the function.  Remove these three lines:

```
                else:
                    print('thank you, have a nice day!\n')
                    break
```

Outdent the two lines immediately above the three that you deleted, and replace **break** with **return**.

There are other improvements you could make too, but that's a start.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is only add a boolean variable that you set to false if the answer of the user is `n`. Please notice also that there was a problem in the code, you don't update the value of `cim` in the proper way. You have to consider that a person could need to input more than one coin, so you have to accumulate the total coins inserted:

```
def vend():

    a = {'item': 'choc', 'price': 1.5, 'stock': 2}
    b = {'item': 'pop', 'price': 1.75, 'stock': 1}
    c = {'item': 'chips', 'price': 2.0, 'stock': 3}
    d = {'item': 'gum', 'price': 0.50, 'stock': 1}
    e = {'item': 'mints', 'price': 0.75, 'stock': 3}
    items = [a, b, c, d, e]
    cim = 0 # cash in machine

    print('welcome to vending machine! \n***************')

    # show items, prices
    def show(items):
        print('\nitems available \n***************')

        for item in items:      
            if item.get('stock') == 0:
                items.remove(item)
        for item in items:
            print(item.get('item'), item.get('price'))

        print('***************\n')
    continueToBuy = True
    # have user choose item
    while continueToBuy == True:
        show(items)
        selected = input('select item: ')
        for item in items:
            if selected == item.get('item'):
                selected = item               
                price = selected.get('price')
                while cim < price:
                    cim = cim + float(input('insert ' + str(price - cim) + ': '))   

                print('you got ' + selected.get('item'))
                selected['stock'] -= 1
                cim -= price
                print('cash remaining: ' + str(cim))
                a = input('buy something else? (y/n): ')
                if a == 'n':
                    continueToBuy = False

                    if cim != 0:
                        print(str(cim) + ' refunded')
                        cim = 0
                        print('thank you, have a nice day!\n')
                        break                        
                    else:
                        print('thank you, have a nice day!\n')
                        break  
                else:
                    continue



vend()
```

Also, I think that this is a good example to introduce object-oriented programming. It allows you to have a better structured code, and let you focus on the logic of want you want to develop. Here is a possible implementation:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, price, stock):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.stock = stock

    def updateStock(self, stock):
        self.stock = stock

    def buyFromStock(self):
        if self.stock == 0:
            # raise not item exception
            pass
        self.stock -= 1

class VendingMachine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.amount = 0
        self.items = []

    def addItem(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def showItems(self):
        print('\nitems available \n***************')

        for item in self.items:      
            if item.stock == 0:
                self.items.remove(item)
        for item in self.items:
            print(item.name, item.price)

        print('***************\n')

    def addCash(self, money):
        self.amount = self.amount + money

    def buyItem(self, item):
        if self.amount < item.price:
            print('You can\'t but this item. Insert more coins.')
        else:
            self.amount -= item.price
            item.buyFromStock()
            print('You got ' +item.name)
            print('Cash remaining: ' + str(self.amount))

    def containsItem(self, wanted):
        ret = False
        for item in self.items:
            if item.name == wanted:
                ret = True
                break
        return ret

    def getItem(self, wanted):
        ret = None
        for item in self.items:
            if item.name == wanted:
                ret = item
                break
        return ret

    def insertAmountForItem(self, item):
        price = item.price
        while self.amount < price:
                self.amount = self.amount + float(input('insert ' + str(price - self.amount) + ': '))

    def checkRefund(self):
        if self.amount > 0:
            print(self.amount + " refunded.")
            self.amount = 0

        print('Thank you, have a nice day!\n')


def vend():

    machine = VendingMachine()
    item1 = Item('choc',  1.5,  2)
    item2 = Item('pop', 1.75,  1)
    item3 = Item('chips',  2.0,  3)
    item4 = Item('gum',  0.50, 1)
    item5 = Item('mints',0.75,  3)
    machine.addItem(item1)
    machine.addItem(item2)
    machine.addItem(item3)
    machine.addItem(item4)
    machine.addItem(item5)

    print('Welcome to the vending machine!\n***************')

    continueToBuy = True
    while continueToBuy == True:
        machine.showItems()
        selected = input('select item: ')
        if machine.containsItem(selected):
            item = machine.getItem(selected)

            machine.insertAmountForItem(item)
            machine.buyItem(item)

            a = input('buy something else? (y/n): ')
            if a == 'n':
                continueToBuy = False
                machine.checkRefund()
            else:
                continue

        else:
            print('Item not available. Select another item.')
            continue

vend()
```

For more information about OOP, see [a resource like this](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/).